# Permissão negada - Logging

Tags: python, flask, logging

Implementei o `Logging` do python em vários projectos de Flask com sucesso. Mas quando tentei implementar novamente o Logging num projecto dá o seguinte `error:IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied`.

Para tentar resolver o problema criei o ficheiro e mesmo assim o error continua. É estranho este error ocorrer depois de ter usado o mesmo código para todos os projetos anteriores.

Supostamente o erro ocorre no seguinte código:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import logging
    logging.basicConfig(filename='error.log', level=logging.WARNING)
    app.run()
```

Comment: qual o usuário que está rodando a aplicação?

Comment: Tenta mudar o local do arquivo.

Comment: Isto está a correr na minha máquina de desenvolvimento. Portanto devia ter as permissões todas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este erro, número **13**, é relacionado a permissões. O processo que está executando o seu website não tem autorização para criar ou modificar o arquivo *error.log* no diretório tentado.

Como seu exemplo é de Flask e executa `app.run()` eu posso assumir que o usuário é você mesmo, pois se trata do webserver de desenvolvimento embutido no Flask.

Então nesse caso, muito provavelmente você está executando seu script de um diretório de desenvolvimento, criado por você, com todas as permissões necessárias. A única conclusão que me resta é que o arquivo *error.log* não está sendo criado dentro deste diretório.

Uma tentativa simples de fazer seu código funcionar é ser mais explícito quanto ao local do arquivo, passando o caminho completo.

Exemplo, assumindo que você deseje *error.log* no mesmo diretório que o script:

Comment: O engraçado é que o arquivo se encontra dentro do projecto Flask, como fiz em todos os outros projectos anteriores.

Comment: coloque um `print os.getcwd()` logo depois do `import logging` para confirmar qual o diretório atual e se realmente é o que você está pensando. Eu muitas vezes prefiro usar caminhos absolutos para o arquivo, evitando assim esse tipo de surpresas.